# SuccessWithWarning in Paypal Mass Pay

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am building a payout system using PayPal's Mass Pay API. According to their documentation, a  message will come back with one of the following status responses:

- "Success"
- "SuccessWithWarning"
- "Failure"
- "FailureWithWarning"

Does anyone know what an example of a "SuccessWithWarning" situation is for the Mass Pay API? I have only been able to simulate "Success" and "Failure" in Sandbox. Even after turning on Negative Testing for my Sandbox account, I was not able to reproduce a "SuccessWithWarning" status with the Mass Pay API. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

For reference:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

Answer (score 1):

The above four values are the possible values for the variable ACK . Not all the API return the "SuccessWithWarning" as the ACK value . This value is applicable only to some API's like SetExpressCheckout API , DoExpressCheckout API etc . You can refer the below link to check what are the possible errors related to a particular API:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3F0O0NTU

Answer (score 0):

I was sent a notification on one of my legacy systems today with the "SuccessWithWarning" response.

```
ACK = SuccessWithWarning
VERSION = 65.1
BUILD = 12896494
L_ERRORCODE0 = 11812
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 = Invalid Data
L_LONGMESSAGE0 = The value of Description parameter has been truncated.
L_SEVERITYCODE0 = Warning
```

So there is one example for you.